# How can I achieve a pseudo-3D camera effect like this?

Tags: xna, 3d, camera, projection, perspective

I am trying to achieve a pseudo-3D camera effect similar to this:

[image: Battle Rotation]

I have gotten the following results using a 3D camera and billboards:

[image: Battle Rotation]
[image: Battle Rotation]
[image: Battle Rotation]

I am now running into the following problems:

1. In the first billboard example, the size discrepancy between when the sprites are at the "front" and "back" is too great. I need to have them be more similar to the above.
2. The bottom y-coordinate of the sprites never seem to change in my example, but they do (slightly) in the example that I want.
3. I need to be able to control how close to the right and left edge of the screen the sprites go to.

In the first billboard example I setup my camera like so:

```
// (float fovxDegrees, float aspect, float znear, float zfar)
this.simpleCamera.Perspective(75f, 1.5f, 0.01f, 400);

// (Vector3 eye, Vector3 target, Vector3 up)
this.simpleCamera.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 5f, 10f), Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
```

My sprites are positioned at the following locations:

```
new Vector3(-4f, 1f, 0f);
new Vector3(-4f, 1f, 1f);
```

Full CSharp code: http://pastebin.com/9G0FDNLs

Billboard HLSL: http://pastebin.com/uB8e3gXU

If you want the grid: http://pastebin.com/R5UCBNWt

Comment: this image is all you are trying to accomplish ? seems like 8 2D points moving on an ellipse and their scale is based of their Y position. you are over complicating this

Comment: @Shiro No, this image is not all I want. I need help building a generic 3D battle world where I can render a ton of 2D sprites in 3D space with the ability to rotate around them. Battle effects, etc...

Comment: those old pseudo 3D games are done in 2D with "homemade" algorithms. apart from your question where I gave you a brief idea of how it can be implemented, (probably 10 but very well thought lines of code), what else you think would be hard to make in the pseudo 3D game you are trying to make ?

Comment: @Shiro I need to be able to render battle effects and be able to rotate around those battle effects. Say for example a lava eruption on an enemy, where I then move the camera in behind the sprites to show them in the foreground and the lava in the background. I also need to have the scaling that happens with perspective.

Comment: It seems like you'd be best off just seeing your project as a 3d one. Use x,y, and z coordinates to position everything, create a camera, and draw billboarded sprites at the xyz-coordinates. To find out how to do all this, please refer to Riemer's XNA tutorials. This is how I've learned to do things like this, and I feel it's a good  place to start. This one explains billboarding (a technique I think you should use): http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding.php

Comment: @Peethor Can billboarding be done without HLSL?

Comment: Absolutely. It won't be as fast as using a custom shader, but it's definitely possible. You just do the same maths, but in your project code instead of in the shader.

Comment: Games that use sprites in 3D environment don't allow camera rolls, so don't bother trying to make rolling makes sense.

Comment: @LieRyan I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @test: in your third image, that rotation requires a roll rotation (in terms of roll/pitch/yaw). Most sprite based games only do yaw and probably a bit of pitch and almost never roll.

Comment: @LieRyan I see. So if I go back to the second gif, how do I make it so that the sprites aren't so small when they rotate around the "back"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, both of which require 3D cameras and projection:

First, give all of your objects a 3D position in the world.

```
// XYZ
Vector3 Position;
```

Next, create a camera with a position and orientation:

```
class Camera
{
    // Position of the camera in the world
    Vector3 Position;
    // Place where the camera is looking
    Vector3 Target;
    // Matrices representing the camera's parameters
    Matrix ViewMatrix;
    Matrix ProjectionMatrix;
}
```

You can update the camera's parameters like this:

```
void UpdateCameraParams()
{
  // Creates a view matrix from where the camera is looking and its position.
  ViewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Target, Vector3.Up);
  // Creates a perspective matrix with 1.2 radian FOV, 16:9 aspect ratio,
  // near plane of 0.01 units, and far plane of 10 units.
  ProjectionMatrix = 
        Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFOV(1.2f, 16.0f / 9.0f, 0.01f, 10.0f);
}
```

Now, the two ways of drawing.

## SpriteBatch, the Hacky Way

You're probably familiar with SpriteBatch already. It's a way of drawing sprites to the screen in screen space. One thing you can do is simply project all of your objects onto the screen, scale them by their distance to the camera, and then render them. This is a hacky way of doing things, because you have to fake perspective and the depth buffer.

Here's how to do it:

```
SpriteBatch.Begin();

// Draw each entity in the scene
foreach(Entity thing in Scene)
{
    // Project its position onto the screen using the camera.
    Vector3 screenPos 
      = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Project(thing.Position, camera.ProjectionMatrix,
                                        camera.ViewMatrix, Matrix.Identity);

    // Determine if its on the screen.
    bool isOnScreen = Viewport.Bounds.Contains((int)screenPos.X, (int)screenPos.Y);

    if(!isOnScreen) continue;

    // Compute the depth and scale of the object.
    float depth = screenPos.Z;
    float scale = 1.0f / depth;

    // Draw it at the appropriate depth and scale.
    SpriteBatch.Draw(thing.Image, new Vector2(screenPos.X, screenPos.Y),
                     thing.SourceRect, thing.Tint, thing.Rotation, thing.Origin,
                     new Vector2(scale, scale), thing.SpriteEffects, depth);

}

SpriteBatch.End();
```

## Textured Billboards, the Correct Way

You can also just create for each sprite a physical 3D model, just a 3D billboard, oriented to face the camera. Then, you can render it like any other XNA 3D geometry. The depth buffer will work flawlessly, you won't have to guess the scale, and perspective will be taken care of correctly. I suggest [this tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Billboarding.php) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually started implemented the billboard method. I have been using [this](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/xnaBillboards4.html) project as an example since it targets XNA 4.0 (whereas Reimer's targets 3.1).

Comment: If possible, can you look at my edit regarding the billboard technique?

Comment: Simply change the FOV of your camera. Larger FOV will result in less depth distortion. Smaller FOV results in more.

Comment: Hmm... I must be missing some concept. If I go with a larger FOV that will make the objects very distant. So how would I create a larger FOV and then zoom(?) in I guess, to the now distant objects?

Comment: Yes, you need to increase the FOV and decrease the distance of the camera.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I'm still very new to the 3D side of this. How would I adjust the distance of the camera? So far all I've been playing around with is the `eye` vector that I can pass into the `LookAt` method (which is doing some matrix magic).

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it. Just move the eye vector so that its really close to where your entities are standing. The idea is to achieve a sort of [dolly zoom effect](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Contra-zoom_aka_dolly_zoom_animation.gif). Come to think of it, I might be wrong about the FOV, you might have to decrease rather than increase it. You can also try using an orthographic camera rather than a perspective one

Comment: I can get similar when tweaking those values: [example (image 4 in post)](http://i.imgur.com/3vBUgaH.gif). But it's still not quite there. Two things: 1) The size discrepency between front and back is still quite big. 2) I can't seem to control how close to the left edge of the screen he goes. He almost fully goes off the right edge, but not so on the left. I want to center him between the screen.

Comment: Ok. So you don't want *any* perspective scaling at all? If that's the case, use an [orthographic camera](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195662.aspx) instead of a perspective camera. As for getting the rotation how you'd like it, that's up to you. Just tune the parameters for how hes rotating until it looks like you want.

Comment: I want the **exact** same rotation and depth as the first image. I'm really struggling with what and how I need to change variables to get this. Can I get this exact effect with billboards or am I wasting my time?

Comment: You're almost there. It looks pretty good already to me. Just needs a bit more tweaking. Why does it need to be *exactly* the same? Can't your game have its own style?

Comment: Long story short I'm recreating the engine from that game, so I want it as close to exact as possible. The tweaking part is where I'm having troubles, I don't know what variables I should be tweaking to give me the closest result.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that it would be best to go fully 3D billboard with this. You can do this without shaders (well, you would use the built in `BasicEffect` which is an already written shader for you).

1. Move the camera away from the scene and decrease the FOV. here's why:

[image]
When you move the camera close to the scene and widen the FOV, the close fighter (blue square) is taking up approx. 1/10 of the screen, but the farther fighter is only 1/15 to 1/20 of the screen which is drawn as a much smaller object.
When moving back from the scene and narrowing the FOV, the close and far fighters appear about the same size with the farther one only slightly smaller instead of a lot smaller. Experiment to find the sweet spot.

2. Raise the position of the camera a bit and point it down to keep scene centered. Experiment to find the sweet spot.
3. Once the camera is looking at the center of the scene, the FOV and the camera distance from the scene will contribute to that.